# JOIN and get value from one row after

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables (simplified for this purpose)

```
Table 1: File
id, name
1, File1
2, File2
3, File3
4, File4

Table 2: Meeting_File
id, meeting_id, file_id
1, 1, 1
2, 2, 2
3, 3, 3
4, 4, 4

Table 3: Meeting
id, name, password
1, Bil1/2016, Password1
2, Bil2/2016, Password2
3, Bil3/2016, Password3
4, Bil4/2016, Password4
```

If the Meeting's password and the File's name share the same Meeting's id, things are easy, we can use

```
SELECT b.password FROM File a 
LEFT JOIN Meeting_File c ON c.file_id = a.id 
LEFT JOIN Meeting b ON b.id = c.meeting_id
WHERE a.id = 1
```

But, in our case, the password is always one row after.

To open File1 which belong to Meeting id = 1, we need the password from Meeting id = 2

To open File2 which belong to Meeting id = 2, we need the password from Meeting id = 3

and so on..

To summarize, we have documents from past meeting which only can be open with password with current meeting.

How to get the password?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your database is poorly designed . you can use some expensive sql like  below

```
SELECT 
    (select password from meeting m where id > mf.meeting_id order by meeting_id limit 0,1) as password
        FROM File f 
        LEFT JOIN Meeting_File mf
        ON (mf.file_id = f.id) 
        WHERE f.id = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks. About the design, please suggest an improvement. Early requirement just need the easy sql syntax, but latter on client change the requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Just add 1:

```
SELECT m.password
FROM File f LEFT JOIN
     Meeting_File mf
     ON mf.file_id = f.id LEFT JOIN
     Meeting m
     ON m.id = mf.meeting_id + 1
WHERE f.id = 1;
```

Comment: forget to mention, the id not necessarily +1 because it's auto increment, and sometimes got deleted, so I have to depend on insert order.

Or if you have suggestion for improvement, most welcome.